# How can I update nodes in Firebase table using Swift?

Tags: function, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

I am quite new at iOS and I am struggling for a while to update Colleagues nodes in Firebase, every time a user changes the workplace address. The logic is quite simple: when someone is changing the workplace he needs to be removed from the existent Colleague node and move to another.

Every time I run the function below I get additional nodes after the first change of address.

This is how my Firebase tables look like.
[image]

Any ideas or thoughts on how to get this right?

```
func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {
    print("Place name: ", place.name)
    print("Place address: ", place.formattedAddress)
    print("Place attributions: ", place.attributions)
    self.placeName.text = place.name + ", " + place.formattedAddress!

    // grab workplace values to be updated in Firebase
    // check for duplicates
    let placeName : String = place.name
    let placeAddress : String = place.formattedAddress!
    let workplaceData = ["place_address":placeAddress,"place_name":placeName]


    /* COLLEAGUES */
    // grab my current workplace id and remove me from the list

    self.prRef.child(self.getUid())
        .observe(.value, with : { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
            // check if this is the same with the one just entered
            let profilesDict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject]
            let workplaceID = (profilesDict?["workplace_id"] as! String)
            self.currentWorkplaceId = workplaceID
            print("the current - inside - workplace_id: \(self.currentWorkplaceId)" )
    })
    print("the current workplace_id: \(self.currentWorkplaceId)" )
    self.collRef.child("\(self.currentWorkplaceId)/\(self.getUid())").removeValue()
    /* end updating workplace for a new, non-existent address in workplaces */

    /* WORKPLACE
     - check for existent worklace formatted address and grab ID
     - create new workplace if doesn't exist, based on a pre-generated ID
     */
    wkRef
        .queryOrdered(byChild: "place_address")
        .queryEqual(toValue: placeAddress)
        .observe(.value, with : { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
            //print("workplace query: \(snapshot)")

            if ( snapshot.value is NSNull ) {
                //print("Address was not found, we have to create it")

                // update workplaces
                let newWorkplaceUpdate = self.db.WKPLACES_REF.childByAutoId()
                self.newWorkPlaceKey = newWorkplaceUpdate.key // get workplace id key

                print("new address, new workplace key: \(self.newWorkPlaceKey)")
                let updateWorkplaceData = ["\(self.newWorkPlaceKey)":workplaceData]
                self.wkRef.updateChildValues(updateWorkplaceData)

            } else { //in case a new address is an existent address

                // take the existent key from workplaces
                for child in snapshot.children {
                    self.newWorkPlaceKey = (child as AnyObject).key as String
                }
                print("workplace key exists, and is : \(self.newWorkPlaceKey)")

                //newWorkPlaceId = key//remove
                //print("existent workplace id: \(newWorkPlaceId)")//remove
            }
            // update profiles
            let profRef = self.prRef.child(self.getUid())
            let updateWorkplaceProfileData = ["workplace_id": self.newWorkPlaceKey, "place_address":placeAddress,"place_name":placeName]
            profRef.updateChildValues(updateWorkplaceProfileData)

            // update colleagues
            self.prRef.child(self.getUid()).observe( .value, with : { (snapshot) in
                let profilesDict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject]
                //print(profilesDict)
                self.collValues = [
                    "full_name":(profilesDict?["full_name"])!,
                    "mobile":(profilesDict?["mobile"])!,
                    "avatar":(profilesDict?["avatar"])!,
                    "role": (profilesDict?["role"])!
                ]
                let colleaguesRef = self.collRef.child("\(self.newWorkPlaceKey)")
                let colleaguesData = ["\(self.getUid())": self.collValues]
                colleaguesRef.updateChildValues(colleaguesData)
            })
    })



    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the calls to **Firebase** made are ***Asynchronous*** , so it takes time to retrieve the value from the firebase, but even before your value is retrieved ,

```
print("the current - inside - workplace_id: \(currentWorkplaceId)" )
```

is executed.

***PS :-*** To check this you can use timer, add a timeInterval , put a print statement  for the global variable inside the function and you will see.....

Comment: thanks @Dravidian I saw that it works inside the function. The reason behind this question is a problem I have querying a couple of relational tables in Firebase and update values in all, based on a user action. Maybe I have to post the full issue here to see if could be a better approach.

Comment: Can you explain in brief what you exactly wanna do/

Comment: I want to remove the current user id ( who is logged in ) from Colleagues table every time he/she is changing the address. ( i have implemented Google Places to autocomplete the address )

Comment: remove the current logged in user from the current Colleagues node where is recorded and create another Colleagues node,  based on the workplace id.